# Issue on TabLayout regarding load data

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I am not experienced on android and I implemented code for Tablayout, where I have six tab and each tab has there ListView where data will come from server. I am using VolleyResponse to fetch the data but all the tab's data come at open time. I need data should be come on swipe and when user will go previous swipe data should not load again. So please guide me what should I do?
Below is my code for fragment.

```
   private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    int numberOfPages=7;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Matches_Tab(), "Matches");
    adapter.addFragment(new NewMatches_Tab(), "New matches");
    adapter.addFragment(new Similar_Matchs_Tab(), "Similar Matches");
    adapter.addFragment(new ShortlistTab(), "ShortListed");
    adapter.addFragment(new Viewed_My_Profile(), "View My Profile");
    adapter.addFragment(new ShortListedMeTab(), "ShortListed Me");
    adapter.addFragment(new Photo_Request_Received(), "Photo Request Received");
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfPages);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Fragment class

```
public class Matches_Tab extends Fragment{
// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;
String email;
public String JSON_URL;
private ListView listView;
public Matches_Tab() {}


private static Matches_Tab instance;

public static synchronized Matches_Tab getInstance(Bundle data){
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Matches_Tab();
        instance.setArguments(data);
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getContext(), "SERIF", "Peddana-Regular.ttf");

    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    JSON_URL = "https://www.maangal.com/maangal_mobile/matches.php?matri_id="+email;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_tab, container, false);
  //  ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    sendRequest();
    //getArguments();
    return view;
}


private void sendRequest(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    showJSON(response);
                    Log.e("Broder Matches s----->",response);
                          }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS = 30000;
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

protected void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    Profile_Match_custom_List cl = new Profile_Match_custom_List(getActivity(), ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.ages, ParseJSON.heights, ParseJSON.communities,ParseJSON.castes,ParseJSON.educations,ParseJSON.occupations,ParseJSON.incomes,ParseJSON.pics,ParseJSON.locations,ParseJSON.shortlist,ParseJSON.expressinterest);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the main issue....? BTW here is link for tab-layout tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: In TabLayout you are using Fragments. fetch data on setUserVisibleHInt() method of fragment and set any flag to check data is load or not.

Comment: Are you using Viewpager for load all fragments?

Comment: ya I am using ViewPager for all tabs @Samir

Comment: You can check my answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `BaseFragment`

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

protected Activity mActivity;

/**
 * isFragmentVisible
 */
private boolean isFragmentVisible;
/**
 * View in onCreateView is ok
 */
private boolean isPrepared;
/**
 * isFirstLoad
 */
private boolean isFirstLoad = true;
/**
 * isForceLoad
 */
private boolean isForceLoad = false;


/**
 * onAttach Activity
 *
 * @param context
 */
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.mActivity = (Activity) context;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container
        , Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    isFirstLoad = true;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity)
            .inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
    initView(view, savedInstanceState);
    isPrepared = true;
    lazyLoad();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


/**
 * want to load data ,need set in onCreateView
 * isPrepared = true;
 */
protected void lazyLoad() {
    if (isPrepared() && isFragmentVisible()) {
        if (isForceLoad || isFirstLoad()) {
            isForceLoad = false;
            isFirstLoad = false;
            initData();
        }
    }
}

public boolean isPrepared() {
    return isPrepared;
}

public boolean isFirstLoad() {
    return isFirstLoad;
}

public boolean isFragmentVisible() {
    return isFragmentVisible;
}

/**
 * use with viewpager
 *
 * @param isVisibleToUser is visible for user
 */
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        onVisible();
    } else {
        onInvisible();
    }
}

/**
 * if you use show hide to set fragment ,do this
 *
 * @param hidden hidden True if the fragment is now hidden, false if it is not
 *               visible.
 */
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    if (!hidden) {
        onVisible();
    } else {
        onInvisible();
    }
}

protected void onVisible() {
    isFragmentVisible = true;
    lazyLoad();
}

protected void onInvisible() {
    isFragmentVisible = false;
}

/**
 * set force load
 */
public void setForceLoad(boolean forceLoad) {
    this.isForceLoad = forceLoad;
}


/**
 * getLayoutId ,like : R.layout.fragment
 *
 * @return
 */
protected abstract int getLayoutId();

/**
 * initView
 *
 * @param view
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
protected abstract void initView(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState);

/**
 * load data here
 */
protected abstract void initData();

}
```

Then load data in `initData` method .

```
@Override
protected void initData() {
   // request here
}
```

**Note**

- the main method is `setUserVisibleHint` and `onHiddenChanged`
- add some boolean flag to determine whether the data has been loaded, view creates etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener to get callbacks for when a page becomes visible.
Check below code.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Add your logic
    } 
});
```

Comment: plz check my updated code and tell me where should I put your code.

Comment: This is the logic i have suggested here. You can implement this method on your activity where you are adding tablayout with View pager. View pager have one method addonPageChangeListener that calls when page changed in viewpager. you can create one callback to fragment using interface.

Comment: what logic will I put here

Comment: This event will trigger whenever you swipe view in viewpager. So, you can call a particular method in fragment for your logic.

Answer (score 1):

## Aternate solution

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
  new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        super.onTabSelected(tab);
        //put your Logic here
    }
});
```

Comment: What will happen on this

Comment: suppose you are on `tab1`and you moving to the `tab2` then you want to do   what is required on `tab2` basically its listens the change of tab

Comment: And suppose if I will go back on previous tab then page will load again or not

Comment: nope for load again you have to build your logic inside `onResume` of `tab1`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ViewPager` and you are getting data for all the tabs in one API call then I suggest you set the offset of the viewpager equal to the number of tabs.

```
ViewPager vp = ...;
vp.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfTabsHERE);
```

NOTE: Only use this if there is not much data to show else you may get a `MemoryOutOfException`.

If you do have a lot of tabs and a lot of data. Using `Singleton` pattern for fragments is a good option.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private static MyFragment instance;

    public static synchronized MyFragment getInstance(Bundle data // if any){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyFragment();
            instance.setArguments(data);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
...
onCreateView{.... getArguments()}
```

Comment: Instead of `adapter.addFragment(new Matches_Tab(), "Matches");` now use, `adapter.addFragment(Matches_Tab.getInstance(data.getMatchesData), "Matches");`

Comment: This will initialize all your fragments with the relevant data and will not reinitialize your fragments. All you have to do is display the data inside `Fragment.onCreateView()`

Comment: what is data on                                                                                                 (adapter.addFragment(Matches_Tab.getInstance(data.getMatchesD‌​‌​ata), "Matches")) When I used it. there is an error. can't resolve symbol data. And check my edited code

Comment: Data is the model class that you be using after getting response from the server